# TAPI3LIB C#.NET - BasicCallControll.Connect crash

Tags: c#, .net

I have a sample code from the MS site, about a TAPI application which creates a call.

The code works. I can actually make a call as well.
Then when I hang up and try again, it crashed on the "connect statement" though I create the object the line before (as per sample code from MS)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TapiSample {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            tapi = new TAPI3Lib.TAPIClass();
            tapi.Initialize();
            foreach (TAPI3Lib.ITAddress ad in (tapi.Addresses as TAPI3Lib.ITCollection)) {
                cbLines.Items.Add(ad.AddressName);
            }

            tapi.EventFilter = (int)(TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLINFOCHANGE |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_DIGITEVENT |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_PHONEEVENT |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLSTATE |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_GENERATEEVENT |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_GATHERDIGITS |
    TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_REQUEST);
            tapi.ITTAPIEventNotification_Event_Event += new TAPI3Lib.ITTAPIEventNotification_EventEventHandler(tapi_ITTAPIEventNotification_Event_Event);
        }

        TAPI3Lib.TAPIClass tapi = null;
        TAPI3Lib.ITAddress line = null;
        int cn = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (line != null) {
                line = null;
                if (cn != 0) tapi.UnregisterNotifications(cn);
            }
            foreach (TAPI3Lib.ITAddress ad in (tapi.Addresses as TAPI3Lib.ITCollection)) {
                if (ad.AddressName == cbLines.Text) {
                    line = ad;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (line != null) {
                cn = tapi.RegisterCallNotifications(line, true, true, TAPI3Lib.TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO, 2);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
            if (cn != 0) tapi.UnregisterNotifications(cn);
        }

        delegate void AddLogDelegate(string text);
        private void AddLog(string text) {
            if (this.InvokeRequired) {
                this.Invoke(new AddLogDelegate(AddLog), new object[] { text });
            }
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, text);
        }

        private void tapi_ITTAPIEventNotification_Event_Event(TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT TapiEvent, object pEvent) {
            try {
                switch (TapiEvent) {
                    case TAPI3Lib.TAPI_EVENT.TE_CALLNOTIFICATION:
                        TAPI3Lib.ITCallNotificationEvent cn = pEvent as TAPI3Lib.ITCallNotificationEvent;
                        if (cn.Call.CallState == TAPI3Lib.CALL_STATE.CS_OFFERING) {
                            string c = cn.Call.get_CallInfoString(TAPI3Lib.CALLINFO_STRING.CIS_CALLERIDNUMBER);
                            AddLog("Call Offering: " + c + " -> " + cn.Call.Address.DialableAddress);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (line == null) return;
            TAPI3Lib.ITBasicCallControl bc = line.CreateCall(teNumber.Text, TAPI3Lib.TapiConstants.LINEADDRESSTYPE_PHONENUMBER, TAPI3Lib.TapiConstants.TAPIMEDIATYPE_AUDIO);
            bc.Connect(false);  // <!------ CRASH HERE ON 2ND TRY
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it that I dont release it? if so, where? Sorry, I have never programmed C# before.

Comment: With me, cbLines stays empty, what should I do to get the lines to show up?

Comment: If the cbLines stay empty it would mean you have no TAPI available resources on your system. Have you checked the modem attached?